# NotesException: Object has been removed or recycled

Tags: xpages

I have a Java package that holds utilities, one of which accesses a Notes database. When I first use this class (called from a session scoped bean), which is static and returns a boolean it always seems to throw an exception on accessing the database object. Subsequent calls work.

My code starts off as follows and throws the exception on either the line to access the database or the line that checks if it is open. I saw some folks have posted issues with static classes.  Is that the issue or is it something else?

```
boolean rtn = false;
    try {
    Session session = ExtLibUtil.getCurrentSessionAsSigner();
    if (session.isValid() == false){
        DebugToolbarBean.get().info("Session is not valid");
    } else if (session == null){
        DebugToolbarBean.get().info("session is null");
    } else{
        DebugToolbarBean.get().info("session is good");
    }

    DebugToolbarBean.get().info("Session server is " + session.getServerName());
    DebugToolbarBean.get().info("session" + session.getServerName());
    ConfigBean configBean = (ConfigBean) ExtLibUtil.resolveVariable(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "configBean");
    String nabDbname = (String) configBean.getValue("UserDominoDirectoryPath");
    DebugToolbarBean.get().info("nab db is " + nabDbname);**
    Database nabDb = session.getDatabase(session.getServerName(), nabDbname , false);

    if (nabDb.isOpen()){
```

In the debug tool bar I get:

```
18:01:29    Error in validatePhase1java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in checkAddressBook: NotesException: Object has been removed or recycled
18:01:29    error in checkAddressBook:dBar says NotesException: Object has been removed or recycled
18:01:29    nab db is Development\External\Cascade\cascweb3final.nsf
18:01:29    sessionCN=Dev01/O=TSPSDev
18:01:29    Session server is CN=Dev01/O=TSPSDev
18:01:29    session is good
18:01:29    Starting
```

The rest of the code (that throws the exception is)

```
} catch (Exception e) {
        rtn = false;
        DebugToolbarBean.get().info("error in checkAddressBook:dBar      " + e.toString() );
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException( "Error in checkAddressBook: " + e.toString());

    }
```

Comment: Must not be the static part... I moved the code into a class in my bean and had the same issue. Failed the first time but worked subsequently.

Comment: Can we see the code for `checkAddressBook`.  It may give a pointer to why the error occurs.  I had a lot of these where the sessionScoped bean was losing Domino objects in the past.

Comment: This is the code for checkAddressBook, I did not include the rest of the code since it never gets there. The exceptions are from my catch statement, I will add to the question above.

Comment: It fails even if I pass in the sessionAsSigner into the call to the Java class from my button on the XPage. Very strange, fails the first time and then trying it the second time always works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't really have a firm answer since I hard-coding in the reference to configBean that seemed to invalidate my session object. That worked. Then I put back the original code and that works now too. Been trying over the last few days to get it to fail again but can't...

Answer (score 1):

You don't by any chance recycle your objects in the `chekcAddressBook` code? That would invalidate the object in all other places where you reference it.

I haven't had these types of problems after having moved to using the [OpenNTF Domino API](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/OpenNTF%20Domino%20APIig2=Bwjpk0Ujg48PCHBO1xvMsQ) ;-)

Comment: I only recycle at the end of checkAddressBook (tried it without recycling but worked the same).

Comment: Just re-read your post. I would really like to see the stack trace.... This will normally tell you exactly where the error is raised - and that normally gives a better idea of what is wrong. If this is related to serialization then I have found that view scope is quite strict on checking that objects can be serialized - whereas the other scopes don't show anything before they fail. So perhaps you could try to switch scopes to see if this changes the first fail/following work experience...

Comment: ok, this is strange. After removing the reference to configBean and hardcoding in a value (path to some Domino databases) that worked fine. So, I then tried putting back the reference to configBean and now that works fine too. I can't get it to fail. I am not sure why that would matter. I know at some point all this code was in a different Domino application and got copied over. But, I am doing the exact same code as before with no further issues. Very strange but I do appreciate all your help!

Comment: John, I gave you the 50 points since you were the closest to helping with a solution.

Comment: @Howard, glad you found a solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sign all design elements using the same developer id. When not all design elements are signed with the same developer id, session will won't be always `null` and `session..getServerName()` throws an Exception from my experience. This is only the case when you use the session 'as signer'.

Comment: It is not failing on the getServerName. If you look at the output the serverName gets outputted.

Comment: I think you should post the full "configBean" class then. I can't understand why it outputs "session is good" after "nab db is....". That could not be happening is I understand above code correctly. (or the bean is initialized twice)

Comment: @FerryKranenburg, the debug lines are shown in reverse order of occurence, so the last message is actually the first.

Comment: @Howard, I'd try setting a variable to session.getServerName() to ensure that it's not lost that value somehow. That would isolate the error to just the existence or non-existence of the session.

Answer (score 0):

If a Bean has an instance member that is a lotus.domino type, it can cause this error when it goes to serialize.

Comment: No, the configBean in the constructor only gets a view, walks the view and then puts the "config values" (which are Strings) into a HashMap that the configBean returns.

Comment: If I remove the reference to configBean, it does work. But, then I have to get the config values from the Notes view which eliminated the fast in-memory access to the config value.

Comment: In the configBean do you have a singleton method to get the Config Values?

Comment: No, get public getters and setters. They don't access Notes objects since all the config values are stored in a HashMap.